# How to immediately shut down Apache camel transactions

Tags: apache-camel

So Apache camel has this graceful shutdown feature that waits 300 seconds, and it's really annoying. I say this because I'm running local testing and I get errors where a request will hang, and I want to abort it by shutting my app down. But then I get stuck waiting for 5 mins for all inflight transactions to finish.

I want the ability to disable this graceful shutdown waiting period for my local testing so I can just kill the whole process and start over. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can set shutdown timeout to some lower value. There are many options to set shutdown timeout value:

- Spring Boot property - `camel.springboot.shutdownTimeout = 1`
- `ShutdownStrategy` property - `getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(1)`
- With environment variable (camel-main only) - `java -DCAMEL_MAIN_SHUTDOWNTIMEOUT=1 ...`
- At runtime with JMX operation `setTimeout()` on MBean `org.apache.camel:context=MyCamel,type=context,name="MyCamel"`

For more details see [Graceful shutdown](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/graceful-shutdown.html).
In Camel 3.1 and later will be default shutdown timeout reduced to 45s - [CAMEL-14336](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14336).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation of the spring boot property: https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/3.7.x/spring-boot.html

> camel.springboot.shutdown-timeout | Timeout in seconds to graceful shutdown Camel. | 300 | Integer

Setting `camel.springboot.shutdownTimeout = 1` in the application test properties was the easiest way to adjust this.